# PHP writing comments on the code

Tags: php

**A.**

```
<?php 
/*
 * Create variable $number1 and $number2.
 */
$number1 = 3;
$number2 = 4;

/*
 * Perform addition and display total on web page.
 */
$total = $number1 + $number2;
echo $total;
?>
```

**B.**

```
<?php 
/*
 * - Create variable $number1 and $number2.
 * - Perform addition and display total on web page.
 */
$number1 = 3;
$number2 = 4;
$total = $number1 + $number2;
echo $total;
?>
```

I would like to write a comments on the code. 
Which one should I prefer?
Any other ways of writing comments are welcome. 
I just want to learn the good ways of writing comments.

Comment: http://www.phpdoc.org/

Comment: did you make some searches before asking?

Answer (score 1):

As a start, understand the difference between [comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php) like

```
/***
 * comment
 */
```

and

```
// comment
```

C-style comments are included into OpCached code, taking up additional memory, one-line comments don't

Answer (score 0):

You could find this easily on google.
Anyway, the comment you use is for more sentences.
There is another method for only one using // .